# Get reply which having most vote in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the reply relationship with like & unlike model. User can like for their best reply and unlike for bad reply.
The like & unlike relationship is almost same,just store in different table.
Now i want to get the replies that having most like & reply that having most unlike, compare them and show only the replies which have most number of vote. How can i achieve it?

In my Discussion Model

```
public function replies(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Forum\Reply');
}
```

In Reply Model

```
public function discussion(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Forum\Discussion');
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function likes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Forum\Like');
}
```

In the like model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function reply(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Forum\Reply');
}
```

Comment: Which table (model) holds the `votes`?

Comment: @ThomasMoors I think Reply has a hasMany relationship to the Like table?

Comment: Yes the reply has many votes( likes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use Eloquents `withCount` here.

So you'd have something like:

```
$mostLikedReply = Reply::withCount('likes')->orderBy('likes_count', 'desc')->first();
$mostUnlikedReply = Reply::withCount('unlikes')->orderBy('unlikes_count', 'desc')->first();
```

Note that `withCount` will place a `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models. That's why the `orderBy` is ordering on what the `withCount` applies, then by grabbing the first result, it should be the highest liked/unliked reply, from here you can compare what you need.

Read more about counting relations [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

Comment: Exactly what i want. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$mostLikedReply = $discussion->replies->sortByDesc(function($reply) {  
    return $reply->likes->count();  
}->first();
```

This will give you the model for the most liked reply.

And the same for most unliked reply and then compare the two? I guess at that point you can maybe merge the whole stuff if you need to.